# Creating sessionFactory in Hql-Initialization

Tags: java, hibernate, static, thread-safety, sessionfactory

I have create a dbadapter for delaing with hibernate.Actually my class looks like this..

```
 public class DBAdapter {
    private static SessionFactory factory;
        private static final ThreadLocal<Session> threadSession = new ThreadLocal(); 

        public static Session OpenConnection() {
      if (factory == null) {
       factory = new Configuration().configure(
       "com/et/hibernatexml/hibernate.cfg.xml")
      .buildSessionFactory();
      }
     Session s = (Session) threadSession.get(); 
         if (s == null)
         { 
            s =factory.openSession(); 
            threadSession.set(s); 
          } 
        return s; 
 }
 public List selectQuery(String QueryString)
  {   try
      {
       Session session=OpenConnection();
       resultlist = query.list();
       }
       finally()
       {
        closeSession();
       }
   }
    public static void closeSession()
    {
      Session session = (Session) threadSession.get(); 
      threadSession.set(null); 
      if (session != null && session.isOpen()) { 
          session.flush(); 
          session.close(); 
      } 
}
```

For getting data from server ,i will do like this..

```
   DBAdapter ob=new DBAdapter();
   ob.setParameter("orgId", orgId);
   List list=ob.selectQuery(queryvalue);
```

My doubt is any issue by dealing like this.Especially because SessionFactory  is static variable??

Comment: You should at least synchronize the OpenConnection() method. No problem with SessionFactory being static, it should be a singleton, since it is expensive to make.

Comment: can u pls clarify by adding sample code??

Comment: http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/hibernate/hibernate-example/hibernate-tools-1.html and http://www.kodejava.org/examples/245.html

Comment: which one should be singleton?? DBAdapter class?? also i am not clear about the term "synchronize"

Answer (score 1):

You do not want more than one threads to create a session factory. It should be a singleton and is by design thread safe. The easiest way to do this with the code you provided is to use the synchronized keyword on the openConnection() method. However, there is no reason to synchronize the part of the code where you create a session and put it on the ThreadLocal instance as well. A rough solution would be like the following

```
public class DBAdapter {
    private static SessionFactory factory;
    private static final ThreadLocal<Session> threadSession = new ThreadLocal<Session>(); 

    private static synchronized SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        if(factory == null) {
            factory = new Configuration().configure("com/et/hibernatexml/hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
        }
        return factory;
    }

    public static Session getSession() {
        Session s = (Session) threadSession.get(); 
        if (s == null) { 
            s = getSessionFactory().openSession(); 
            threadSession.set(s); 
        } 
        return s; 
     }
}
```

Comment: My main doubt is each time when create an Object of object of DBAdapter,it will create factory??..Or it is only one time??

Comment: The class DBAdapter is an utility class with only static methods. No need to create an instance of it ever. Either way, instance creation of this class does not run the static initializers. The ThreadLocal will be created the first time this class is loaded by the JVM and the SessionFactory the first time a thread tries to get a Session. I would gently recommend that you read a good java HandBook like the SCJP6 one by Kathy Sierra.

Comment: currently i have a method "public List selectQuery" in DBadapter.That also to be static method???

Comment: It might as well be. However I would modularize the code a bit. Also add a catch block to your try/finally. Ideally you would like to implement transaction management as well... Anyway, you are off to a decent start, keep digging.

Comment: @dkateros..thank u very much..if i have any doubt i will ask..after testing properly,i will mark ur comment as answer..

Comment: i have commit method in DBadapter..public static void commitTransaction(){ 
        Transaction tx = (Transaction) threadTransaction.get(); 
        try { 
            if ( tx != null ) { 
                tx.commit(); 
            } 
             
            threadTransaction.set(null); 
             
        } catch (HibernateException ex) { 
            rollbackTransaction(); 
             
            throw ex; 
        } 
    }        Here "tx.commit();" always throws exception,when initialize DBadapter object in class level(like DBadapter ob=new DBAdapter()..what is the reason??